# Two Excel Documents - Finding & Merging details together?

Tags: excel, merge, excel-2007

Im struggling to find an answer with regards to this. I basically have 8000 (many of which are duplicates) part numbers from a supplier, and also have a separate document with the pricing for all those part numbers. Now, without the need of manually copy and pasting each and every price in association to the equivalent part number, is there an easy way in which I can type in excel or function that will enable excel to locate the part number and put its price the column next to it?

Comment: take a look at the tutorials on [ExcelUser](http://www.exceluser.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both datasets have unique part numbers on them, and every part number that is in the first set is in the price list, this sounds like a perfect job for a Vlookup.

Suppose I have two tables. The Part Table:

```
        A
1    PartNumber
2    123
3    987
.    ...
50    123
```

and the price table:

```
        A          B       
1    PartNumber   Price
2    123          $10.00
3    987          $99.00
.    ...           ...
10    123          $1.45
```

We want to add price to table A using a Vlookup. Vlookups work like this.

=Vlookup(
             A Partnumber in the parts table, a range of cells in the price table that has              partnumber as the left most column, 
       and includes the price column, the number of the column that has the values we want                to return which is price in our case)

so using this in the Part Table, we have:

```
        A         B
1    PartNumber   Price
2    123          =Vlookup(A2,PriceTable.$A$1:$B$10,2)
3    987
.    ...
50    123
```

You can copy that formula all the way down to populate your new price column.

EDIT: Here's a pretty decent walk through of what Vlookup is and how to use it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Comment: Perfect! To think I now have the correct prices for 8000 products within 30 seconds. Thanks!